# How to retrieve Fingerprint device's data in a Web Browser using Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, fingerprint

I am developing an Online Attendance System.I have a **biometric fingerprint device** plugged in to my PC and I want to get the **fingerprint** data in my `angular` app running in the browser so that I can authenticate it.How can i allow my browser to read the data from that **USB device**.I have read about some SDKs like `WebUSB` by `Google` but I am not sure whether it is the right technology.

Answer (score 0):

`WebUSB` seems like promising though available from Chrome 64 only.

People using other browsers & older versions may not be able to use it.

> https://caniuse.com/#search=WebUSB

Also, no polyfills are available for WebUSB now.

Comment: Then What do you suggest?